# Adding cities names from geometry

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have a map of Chile that shows with different colors which regions were treated and which not. I want to add the names of each region on the left of the map, with each name close to the respective region. For now I have the following code and results:

```
mapas_regiones %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = as.factor(treatment)))  +
  labs(title = "Regiones tratadas",  
       caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia en base de reportes de Carabineros y chilemapas") +
  coord_sf()   +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("skyblue2", "dodgerblue4")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Treatment"))
```

[image]

In my data (mapas_regiones) I have a column called "nombre_region" that contains all the names that I want to add.

I really appreciate your help and time :)

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the [ggsflabel](https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/index.html) package.